# rename error while using nedb

Tags: node.js, nedb

while using [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), I get rename error as

```
/home/rajiv/Coding/vote-for-change/node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:77
    if (err) { throw err; }
            ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/rajiv/Coding/vote-for-change/logs/votersLog~' -> '/home/rajiv/Coding/vote-for-change/logs/votersLog'
```

I am connecting to the database as:

```
var db = new Datastore({
    filename: '/home/rajiv/Coding/vote-for-change/logs/votersLog',
    autoload: true
});
```

why am I getting rename error?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably creating multiple instances of the datastore with the same filename.

Credit to this issue: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/issues/136

Answer (score 0):

The path should be pointed correctly.you cannot simply use absolute path ("/home/rajiv...") .First check your current directory using path,then route it accordingly.

```
var path = require('path');
console.log(path.join(__dirname))
new Datastore({
    filename: (path.join(__dirname)+"/home/rajiv/Coding/vote-for-change/logs/votersLog"),
    autoload: true
});
```

Comment: what are you getting in console.log

Answer (score 0):

That's a generic error. You can get it lots of different ways, without getting any additional useful information.

You need to reproduce the problem in a small simple sample and experiment with things like the pathname to see what triggers it. Best of luck.